# GAS内で呼び出したいパスワード,id,セキュリティ上問題のある情報の管理について

Tags: api, google-apps-script

とあるAPIを定期的に呼び出したいのですが、実行はトリガーを使用します。
パスワードやID,トークンのハードコーディングは問題があるため
ソースコードとは別に保管する必要があると思います。

以前はプロジェクトのプロパティに
ユーザーのプロパティが存在したみたいですが、
現在は廃止されているようです。

この代替えになる機能はあるのでしょうか？

全てのプログラムに共通すると思いますが
パスワード,IDについて
手動で実行場合はこちらでパスワードを都度入力すれば分には、問題ありませんが
自動実行となると、どこかに保管しないといけないため
基本的な考え方を知りたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

もともと、ユーザプロパティはユーザ毎の情報を格納するモノというものでもありませんでした（何よりも長年放置されてそして消えました）

さて、Access Tokenや情報を格納するにあたり、セキュアにしたいという事であるならば

１．ユーザにはHTML ServiceのUIだけを利用させ、スプレッドシートは非公開にしておく
２．各ユーザのGoogle Driveに配置したJSONファイルを読み書きさせる（もちろん非公開）
３．ライブラリ機能を介して、特定のスプレッドシートに保存しuserのメアドを取得して検索し返す仕組みを用意する。

の３択になるかと思います。
一番ベターなのは、２．かなと。自分は３．もよく利用します。

**[Google Apps Scriptでプロパティを利用する](https://officeforest.org/wp/2019/04/30/google-apps-script%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E3%81%AF%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%91%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%82%92%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86/#i-12)**

Comment: 2.がシンプルで良さそうでしたが、DriveAppの使用が管理者権限上使用不可できませんでした。
3について、特定のスプレッドシートに保存しuserのメアドを取得して検索し返す仕組みについて、userがメアドを偽り検索する事は考えられないでしょうか？幼稚な質問ですみません

Comment: メアドはログインしてる情報から自動取得させるので、偽ってる場合、アカウントが乗っ取られているのと同義なので、考慮の必要はないと思います。また、DriveAppが使えないのではなく、そのフォルダがユーザのフォルダじゃないのではないでしょうか。特定のメソッドだけNGにされてる？

Comment: getFileById(id)　マイドライブ直下に保存したテキストデータid
getRootFolder()
こちらは
「使用しようとしている機能は、ドメイン管理者により無効にされています」となっていたりします。
Folders = AppDriver.getFolders()は制限されていませんでした。
Folders.getContinuationToken()　こちらはOK
Folders.hasNext() NG
Folders.next() NG
幾つか試してみました。